# Google Sheets Import XML text value will not display

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import some energy data into a Google Sheet, but can't seem to get the value to appear since it is just text in the HTML line, and shows up as --,--- in the output. I have tried adding /text() to the XPath but that is still not working either.

Website with data to import:

http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/default.aspx

Formula in Google Sheets:

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/default.aspx","//div[@class='overview-large-number']")`

Also tried the follwoing Xpath with the same --,--- being displayed.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/text()
```

Screen Shot of Webpage:

[Caiso Webage with Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnvKV.png)

HTML Element with Data:

```
<div class="overview-large-number">41,946 <span>MW</span></div>
```

Screen Shote of Google Sheets current Output:

[Google Sheets Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkJqV.png)

Thank you in advanced for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is populated after the page loads, so you can't use `ImportXML()`. The data is requested via HTTP Get on the URL `http://www.caiso.com/outlook/SP/stats.txt` and is returned in JSON format.

1. Get the ImportJSON script from [here](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) and add it to your sheet (Tools > Script Editor).
2. This should be enough to get you started:

```
=Transpose(ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(
{"AvailableCapacity","CurrentSystemDemand","todayForecastPeakDemand","histDemand","TodaysPeakDemand","tomorrowsForecastPeakDemand"},
ImportJSON("http://www.caiso.com/outlook/SP/stats.txt"),2,0)))
```

Note that the Historical Peak value is already a string, so you may have to do some extra work to get the number out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the script file and this solution worked. How did you know where to find the URL with the data Request? And for my reference since it was a .aspx url, that is how you knew it would need to request information outside of the current page?

Comment: @Cory I opened up the Network Monitor in my browser (F12) and looked for XHRs.